# C# How to load a domain hosted textfile to Rich Textbox?

Tags: c#, text, hyperlink, richtextbox

Ok my question is how to do the following action , i have a textfile hosted in my website and the link is something like http://exampledomain.example/updatelog.txt , is there a way to load the text from that file into a **RichTextbox** witouth downloading it ?

I tried something like this but i get URI error and idk how to implement that URI thing ...

```
richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(http://exampledomain.example/updatelog.txt);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without downloading it? No. That wouldn't even make sense. But you can download it then display it, by using [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx).

```
WebClient wc=new WebClient();
richTextBox1.Text=wc.DownloadString("http://exampledomain.example/updatelog.txt");
```

Note that you may want to use the async methods that are available in order to avoid tying up your UI thread or to improve speed.

Using `System.IO.File` is only for local files.

Comment: hmm not working i get an error , tried this [code] WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                Stream data = wc.OpenRead("http://********.clan.su/updatelog.txt");
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
                string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
                richTextBox1.Text = s;
                data.Close();
                reader.Close();[code] and still same error

Comment: mason's code works just fine. Of course the 1st error may simply mean what it said: that you don't have permission to download the file from the site. Why are you bringing in a StreamReader now???

Comment: @Maxim There's no need to use StreamReader, as the code I posted should work just fine. If you get an error, it's **crucial** that you tell us what the error is.

Comment: nvm , i worked a bit on the code , added a new private void for text display and it work just fine :) thx for help and for all who want to use this code you might want to use this too `code`private void copy_text_to_textbox(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
        WebBrowser wb = (WebBrowser)sender;
        wb.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", false, null);
        wb.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null);
        richTextBox1.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
        }

Comment: There is no need for a web browser. And using the clipboard will probably confuse the user. Try the code I provided, then let us know what problem you run into.